# xampp development: creating project(folders and files) in htdocs folder

Tags: php, linux, apache, xampp, htdocs

I've been using xampp to develop on windows with success but as recently I decided to make a change and start developing on Linux. I successfully installed xampp onto my linux machine. and the Apache sever is running "localhost". opt/lampp/htdocs is where Apache project resources are stored. the htdocs folder permission is restricting read and write, and i can't create folders and files to start my projects. I tried change permission for the folders but to no success.

How do i start developing on xampp severe and add files to /opt/lampp/htdocs

please advice ! ! !

Comment: login as root then `chmod -R 777 opt/lampp/htdocs`?

Comment: Do you mind removing those `! ! !`. Do you have more problems?

Answer (score 6):

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs `
```

777 is the permission where you,group and other get all permission -R is any changes will affect in subdirectories and directories of subdirectories `htdocs`. where adding read=4;write=2 and execute=1 makes it 7.

Comment: [You should not give your web root 777 permissions at all.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777)